# Haskell- Encipher function

Tags: haskell

I am creating function encipher in HASKELL. This is what I have so far.

```
encipher :: Eq a => [a] -> [b] -> [a] -> [b]
encipher _ _ [] = []
encipher xs ys (z:zs) = if f == []
                then z:encipher xs ys zs
                else snd (head f) : (encipher xs ys zs)
    where t = zip xs ys
    f = filter ((== z) . fst) t
    

p9tests = [encipher ['A'..'Z'] ['a'..'z'] "THIS" == "this"]
```

where I test it with p9tests. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I am getting an error.

Comment: I am getting an error on f = filter ((== z) . fst) t

Comment: parse error on input `f' is what error I get

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is indentation. All definitions under `where` need to be indented at the same level.

So to fix your particular error, you could indent `f` to the level of `t` on the line above:

```
    where t = zip xs ys
          f = filter ((== z) . fst) t
```

Or you could go the other way and bring `t` to `f`'s level:

```
    where 
    t = zip xs ys
    f = filter ((== z) . fst) t
```

Comment: I fixed that and still getting errors. Can you please help me with indented

Comment: If you're getting a different error, please post a different question. Also, if you are getting an error, it is usually a good idea to tell whoever is helping you what that error actually is, so that they don't have to guess.